# Как создать чат на Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Доброе время суток. Я начинающий разработчик, поэтому хочу написать свой мессенджер в качестве проекта на Kotlin. Просмотрев различные статьи в интернете, видела различный стек для реализации, но в силу своей неопытности не могу выбрать подходящий. Видела, что кто-то использует Firebase, кто-то на сокетах отыгрывается. Посоветуйте, пжлст, что лучше использовать в моей ситуации. Буду очень благодарна!

Comment: Вам нужен алгоритм? Или список библиотек для реализации?

Comment: Библиотеки, которые проще осваиваются на моем уровне

Comment: Если вы не знаете что вам проще освоить, то мы тем более - мы ничего не знаем о ваших знаниях и способностях. Вы видели статьи - выберите ту, которая вам понятнее и пробуйте. В любом случае это будет полезный опыт. Или вы хотите сразу топовое приложение за 2 дня состряпать?

Comment: Благодарю. Могли бы тогда и не писать, если вы не знаете, что ответить))

Comment: @ВладиславаЧеркасова ваш вопрос слишком широкий. Вы спрашиваете "что лучше использовать в моей ситуации", но никакая ситуация не описана. Если же это учебный проект, то подойдут любые технологии, с которыми вам интересно поиграться.

Comment: Проект действительно учебный. Просто я особо не знаю на чем можно реализовать мессенджер, кроме Firebase. Может есть какие-то другие актуальные популярные технологии? Просто учитывая то, что я не так давно в этом деле, хотелося бы что-то под свой уровень подобрать. Не слишком замудренное на данном этапе для освоения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имеется опыт работы с сокетами, то на сокетах.
Так же работа с сокетами даст тебе больше практических знаний и понимания что происходит под капотом.

Firebase будет чуть попроще за счёт готового простого API и большого количества гайдов.

Я бы сделал на сокетах хотя бы потому что очень малое количество компаний в России используют Firebase в своих проектах :)
Соотвественно понимание прицнипов работы с сокетами даст тебе больше полезных знаний.

P.S. Это мое личное мнение, на основе моего опыта, так как на данный вопрос нельзя дать **точный** ответ :)